# ANOVA and tukey test on categorical variables

Tags: anova, tukey-hsd-test

I have a data frame like the one below, I want to apply an anova test and tukey post hoc test analysis.

```
mydf<-data.frame(Group=rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each=10), Gender=sample(rep(c("F", "M"), each=20), 40, replace=F))
```

That's what I have tried so far and does not work

```
aov <- aov(Group ~ Gender, mydf)
summary(aov)
```

Comment: The independent variable for an ANOVA needs to be numeric, yours is a factor. You need a different test.

Comment: Can you please suggest what could I use? Cheers

Comment: What are your variables and what is your objective?

Comment: I want to do statistical test across the `Group` for the variable `Gender` and a post hoc test to check where is the significance.

Comment: How about a chi-square test of independence on the full table (4 x 2 table)?  It's not clear what you want to determine with your post-hoc analysis.  The way you expressed the model, the independent variable has only two levels, so a significant omnibus test would imply that these two levels are different.

Comment: I used fisher test to check if there is a statistical difference in `gender` across the groups A, B, C, D. Now I want to determine where is the significance by checking with a post hoc analysis among each group comparison: A vs B; A vs C and so on.

Comment: You could do something like you are proposing:  A series of fisher tests on the 2 x 2 component tables (A/B x F/M, and so on).  Correct for multiple hypothesis tests.  This may not be an ideal approach, since each test ignores the rest of the counts that were in the larger table, but it makes sense.  I think the model you are proposing now is *Gender ~ Group*, which could be modeled with logistic regression followed by the group separations with the *emmeans* package.